# I am not able to traverse from the last step to the first step in a multistep form

Tags: 6, forms

I have created a multistep form with five steps using programatically. Is there any way to traverse to first step form the fifth step?
I have created multistep form as given in [example](http://www.drupal.org/project/examples) module. In the module, each step gives previous and next link only, and I am not able to go to the first step directly from the fifth step.

Comment: What Drupal version are you using?

Comment: I am using drupal 6.20

Comment: I switch the question from d7 to d6 because of the previous comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example module uses a value stored in `$form_state['storage']` to indicate which step the form is in, when it is being built. You could add a button with a custom submit handler that unsets this value or set it to the value needed for the step you want to show. Also remember to set `$form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;`.

On a side note, if you want to make multi step forms, the [ctools](http://drupal.org/project/ctools) multi step form wizard API can help you doing a lot of these things for you.

Comment: Where is the documentation for the ctools Form API?